# Catching SQLException instead of Spring DataIntegrityViolationException in unit testing

Tags: java, sql, spring, unit-testing

I am writing unit test to  test failed update in DB by using stored procedure. I have a stored procedure which update one of the table. From test I am sending incorrect data(i.e. data that violate integrity constraint in table) in stored procedure. So I was expecting SQLException but it is throwing Spring's DataIntegrityViolationException. So my question is:
Shouldn't catching SQLException be the correct way as it is more generic?

```
@Test(expected = SQLException.class)
public void testFailedSaveOp() {
    myService.savePerson(garbagePersonData);
}
```

Comment: So is the problem that the exception you are seeing is different from what you expect, or that your `@Test` annotation doesn't notice the exception when you think it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring translates generic SQL exceptions into more specific ones (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLExceptionTranslator.html). Most JDBC methods just throw SQLException, which is very broad and doesn't really tell you what want wrong. Spring tries to provide you with more specific exceptions that you might want to handle differently.

In a more general sense, think about why you don't throw `Exception` everywhere. There are more specific exceptions that give you more information as to what happened that you might want to handle differently.